# How do I evaluate a function into a matrix in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I've got a function that defines a matrix in terms of it's `i` and `j` coordinates:

```
f: {y+2*x}
```

I'm trying to create a square matrix that evaluates this function at all locations.

I know it needs to be something like `f ' (til 5) /:\: til 5`, but I'm struggling with rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rephrasing your question a bit, you want to create a matrix A = [a<sub>ij</sub>] where a<sub>ij</sub> = f(i, j), i, j = 0..N-1.

In other words you want to evaluate `f` for all possible combinations of i and j. So:

```
q)N:5;
q)i:til[N] cross til N; / all combinations of i and j
q)a:f .' i;             / evaluate f for all pairs (i;j)
q)A:(N;N)#a;            / create a matrix using #: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/take/
0 1 2  3  4
2 3 4  5  6
4 5 6  7  8
6 7 8  9  10
8 9 10 11 12
```

P.S. No, `(til 5) /:\: til 5` is not *exactly* what you'd need but close. You are generating a list of all *pairs* i.e. you are pairing or joining the first element of `til 5` with every element of (another) `til 5` one by one, then the second , etc. So you need the join operator (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/join/):

```
(til 5),/:\: til 5
```

Comment: This is a very very helpful answer, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You were close. But there is no need to generate all the coordinate pairs and then iterate over them. [Each Right Each Left](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right) `/:\:` manages all that for you and returns the matrix you want.

```
q)(til 5)f/:\:til 5
0 1 2  3  4
2 3 4  5  6
4 5 6  7  8
6 7 8  9  10
8 9 10 11 12
```